# Access a Swift REPL in Cocoa programs

Tags: cocoa, swift, read-eval-print-loop, lldb, f-script

I can attach LLDB to a program written in Swift and access the REPL, either from within Xcode or by running:

```
lldb -n ProcessName
(lldb) repl
  1>
```

However, if I attach LLDB to a process which doesn't have the Swift runtime, the REPL isn't very useful. For example:

```
lldb -n Finder
Process 218 stopped
Executable module set to "/System/Library/CoreServices/Finder.app/Contents/MacOS/Finder".
Architecture set to: x86_64-apple-macosx.
(lldb) repl
  1> import Cocoa
error: Couldn't lookup symbols:
  __swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swiftAppKit
  __swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swiftCoreGraphics
  __swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swiftObjectiveC
  __swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swiftDispatch
  __swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swiftDarwin
  __swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swiftFoundation
```

Any idea on how to load the Swift runtime into a process which isn't linked against it already? This could be a very useful alternative to e.g. injecting F-Script.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

dlopen() to the rescue!

Download [this script](https://gist.github.com/Crazor/a6d29539e57be36d20d3) and save it e.g. to ~/.lldb/inject-swift-repl

Then run `lldb -n Finder --source .lldb/inject-swift-repl` to inject all necessary libraries. Note that you need to disable SIP to mess with the Finder. Also note that sometimes I had to exit LLDB and re-run the script, because some dlopen calls failed and returned 0.

Comment: Can someone help me turn this into a script? I'd like to put this into my lldb init file, so I can just run "inject-swift"...

Comment: With Xcode 6 Beta 4, libswiftAppKit.dylib needs libswiftQuartzCore.dylib. I've updated the [Gist](https://gist.github.com/Crazor/a6d29539e57be36d20d3) accordingly.

Comment: I found useful to: ```find /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/ -name "libswift*"``` since i didn't found the dylib in the exact same path

Comment: I've updated the answer and [the gist](https://gist.github.com/Crazor/a6d29539e57be36d20d3) for 10.12 and Xcode 8.3.1

Answer (score 1):

For Xcode 10/Swift 4.2 I had to load the libs in this order

```
process load /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphonesimulator/libswiftCore.dylib
process load /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphonesimulator/libswiftDarwin.dylib
process load /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphonesimulator/libswiftObjectiveC.dylib
process load /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphonesimulator/libswiftRemoteMirror.dylib
process load /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphonesimulator/libswiftSwiftOnoneSupport.dylib
process load /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphonesimulator/libswiftsimd.dylib
process load /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphonesimulator/libswiftDispatch.dylib
process load /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphonesimulator/libswiftCoreFoundation.dylib
process load /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphonesimulator/libswiftCoreGraphics.dylib
process load /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphonesimulator/libswiftFoundation.dylib
process load /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphonesimulator/libswiftCoreData.dylib
process load /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphonesimulator/libswiftAssetsLibrary.dylib
process load /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphonesimulator/libswiftModelIO.dylib
process load /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphonesimulator/libswiftos.dylib
process load /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphonesimulator/libswiftMetal.dylib
process load /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphonesimulator/libswiftNetwork.dylib
process load /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphonesimulator/libswiftCoreImage.dylib
process load /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphonesimulator/libswiftQuartzCore.dylib
```